# no valid OpenPGP data found when building docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, openpgp

When building a docker image the following step, which happens after downloading nodejs to verify nodejs authenticy

```
gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 9554F04D7259F04124DE6B476D5A82AC7E37093B
```

reults **sometimes** in:

```
[0m[91mgpg: requesting key 4EB7990E from hkp server ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net
[0mgpgkeys: key FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E not found on keyserver
[91mgpg: [0m[91mno valid OpenPGP data found.
[0m[91mgpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Is this an issue of the hkp server being down? And how can i fix it?

Comment: Maybe due to using an old key ? As it says the key is not found on keyserver

Comment: Sometimes the key works, sometimes fails....

Comment: Maybe due to docker cache or something ? can you try to build with `--no-cache`

Comment: i could try that, i also got a suggestion that it could be caused by RAM problems

Comment: Is there a steps to reproduce this issue ?

Comment: absolutely random.... we were thinking, maybe the keyservers are not reachable, but then the errormessage should be different...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189655/discussion-between-mostafa-hussein-and-gobliins).